# How to add a condition for ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, html, angular, clarity

I am creating a table using Clarity.
They have their own syntax, `clrDgItems`, but the structure is the same as ngFor.

I want to create an loop for my table, which filters the first 10 items, and then a second table which only shows items 11-20.

You should also be able to go to the next page. That will say, first table to update to items 21-30 and second table to 31-40

My first thoughts was something like,

```
ngFor="let employee of employees; i as index; i < firstMaxIndex;"
ngFor="let employee of employees; i as index; i > firstMaxIndex && i < secondMaxIndex"
```

But ngFor loop doesnt work like that, and I get the error: `NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token <`

Comment: I suppose next statement can be condition, would that won't help instead of clubbing them together?

Comment: Do you might explain more detail?

Comment: The condition should go inside `*ngFor` context, like this: `<div *ngIf="i < firstMaxIndex">...</div>`

Comment: @Bharat You right, I am used to for-loops in C#, where the condition and declare is in the same parameters!

Comment: @Lbsn Oh, thanks! I just thought it was possible to make both in ngFor as in C# for-loop. 
But the thing is that it's a whole different language, and they won't have the same structures, which I need to get in my head

Comment: @Abinesh already posted it :). To me it makes more clean and readable code, like splitting the loop and condition as two different responsibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to separate out the condition and loop as below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let employee of employees; i as index;">
    <div *ngIf="i > firstMaxIndex && i < secondMaxIndex">
        // add elements or display values based on your needs.
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use slice

```
{{ value_expression | slice : start [ : end ] }}
```

So like this:

```
ngFor="let employee of employees | slice : 0 : firstMaxIndex"

ngFor="let employee of employees | slice : firstMaxIndex : secondMaxIndex"
```